# Using 'several' and 'some'

Tags: determiners

What is the difference between these two?

> Ann has **some** nieces.
>   Ann has **several** nieces.

OALD defines *[some](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/some_1?q=some)* as:

> 3) a large number or amount of something
>   4) a small amount or number of something

and *[several](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/several_1?q=several)* as:

> more than two but not very many

Does this mean that *some* is more than *several*? How can I use them correctly?

The question asks " does Annie have any nephews or nieces ?

Comment: I'm not so sure that this question is "entirely answerable with a dictionary." I would have been more inclined to close it as "not providing enough details." Have a look at our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post on meta, and follow the guidelines there. If you can explain where you looked for an answer and why you're still confused, we can reopen this question, and answer it. I think it could be an excellent question.

Comment: Sanjar, if you compare the definitions of *some* and *several* in a dictionary, do you still have a question? Please add some more information to your question so we can better andwer it.

Comment: I agree with J.R. here. I guess that the OP's confusion is along the lines of another question posted not long ago, [“We have known each other for some years now” - so is it a long time or short time?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/70385/3281). I took the liberty of editing the question based on that guess. Please feel free to edit my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You use **several** with **countable nouns**, which means nouns that can be made plural... for example dogs, cats, cars...

I have **several cars**. I drink **several cups** of coffee in the morning.

You use **some** with **non-countable nouns**... nouns that are always singular.

For example: coffee, sand, money. It means a small amount
I have **some money** in the bank.
I usually drink **some coffee** in the morning.

Comment: I disagree - it's perfectly normal to say "I have some friends in Mexico" or "there are some apples on the table." I don't think it's as simple as count vs non-count.

Comment: No problem, but this isn't a fixed rule for use. There are several/some ways to say something. But in this case I mean **several ways** and don't be wrong if to say some.
The better indicative will be what the speaker means.
This is an explanation of how to use the terms.
More explanation here: http://the-difference-between.com/some/several